# Getting mysqli store result as string

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to find the corresponding bookId for the bookName received from post in a way to avoid errors caused by quotes within the books name.

I am attempting to bind the param to `$stmt` as `$bookName` and storing the result as `$stmt` but

```
echo $stmt;
```

gives this error:

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_stmt could not be
>   converted to string

So I am not sure what I am doing...

```
  $bookName = trim($_POST['bookName']);

  $sql = "SELECT bookId FROM Book WHERE bookName = ?";

  if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $bookName);
      if((mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))){
          mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
      }
      else{
            header("location: error.php");
      }
  }
```

I was to save the bookId as $bookId

The following code does what I needed

```
  if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $bookName);
      if((mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))){
          $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM))
            {
                foreach ($row as $r)
                {
                    $bookId = $r;
                }

            }
       }
      else{
            header("location: error.php");
      }
  }
```

Comment: You cannot echo a Statement handle its not a scalar variable

Comment: Why not do `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $bookName);` as yo already have the value in there

Comment: I think you have to see this link in documentation [DocumentationLink](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)
**See Example Two**

Comment: Yes That's what I needed. Thanks Er.Amit Joshi!

Comment: You are using the `mysqli-stmt.store-result` function with wrong conception. In my opinion.  @user2892730
Kindly Mark my response as anser below. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confused in between two functions `mysqli_stmt_store_result` and `mysqli_stmt_get_result` have to see this link in documentation.

You have to use `mysqli_stmt_get_result` function.

[mysqli_stmt_get_result Documentation Link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)

```
if((mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))){
      mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
  }
```

Replace above code with

```
if((mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))){
     // mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt); not to use

     $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
     echo $row;  //as i dont have database details i hope this work.

  }
```

*See Example Two in documentation link for more certification.*

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of your answer here. Don't post link-only answers

Comment: Can you share some example code? This is still a rather short explanation about what is going wrong

Comment: @user2892730 updated as per my best knowledge and question details. 
 kindly update my code if any correction is needed .

Comment: @Martin actually i typed a answer after very long period. Thanks for your update